# Parse Error in PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

The following code:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

?>
```

Generates this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   $end in
>   /home/idghosti/public_html/testground/mma/include/header.php
>   on line 26

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: yikes, so many answers so fast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the closing brace "}" after the statement:

```
$self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

It should be:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
  $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a "}" before the end.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
} // This is missing
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely missing a curly bracket.

**Your code *should* be:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
  $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the curly bracket "}" before closing the php tag "?>"

Answer (score 0):

You got a curly bracket too much...

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
  $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>
```

Comment: You got two curly brackets too few!